# No puedo quitar scroll horizontal

Tags: html, css

No puedo quitar el scroll horizontal, el problema me aparece en la sección del `#work`. Intente con `overflow-x: hidden`, cambiar el tamaño de los `width` y aun asi sigue pasando.

Este es el código:

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lobster&family=PT+Sans:wght@700&display=swap');
*{
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
}
.container{
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif;
}
header{
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #2a9d8f;
    position: fixed;
}
nav{
    display: flex;
    
}
nav p{
    padding-top: 10px;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 2em;
    margin-left: 2%;
}
nav span{
    color: #f4a261;
}
nav ul{
    display: flex;
    margin-right: 0%;
}
nav li{
    list-style: none;
    padding: 20px 20px;
}
nav a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 1.5em;
}
nav li:hover{
    background-color: #f4a261;
}

#home{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #264653;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
h1{
    font-family: 'Lobster', cursive;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 3em;
}
#home p{
    color: #f4a261;
    font-size: 1.5em;
}

#work{
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    background-color: #f4a261;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    padding-bottom:10%;
}
#work h1{
    padding-top: 5%;
}
.line{
    width: 200px;
    height: 3px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    background-color: #fff;
}
.grid{
    margin-top: 5%;
    width: 90%;
    display:flex;
}
.project{
    width: 25%;
    height: 300px;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
}
.project a{
  text-decoration:none;
}
.project img{
  width:100%;
  height:90%;
}
.project p{
  width:100%;
  height:10%;
  margin-top:-5px;
  background-color: #264653;
  text-align:center;
  font-size:1.3em;
  color:#fff;
}
.project span{
  color: #2a9d8f;
  visibility:hidden;
}
.project:hover span{
  visibility:visible;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Portfolio</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/5dc3ef515d.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <header>
        <nav>
          <p>M<span>R</span></p>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#work">Work</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </header>

      <section id="home">
        <h1>I'm Matias Rubiolo</h1>
        <p>a web developer</p>
      </section>

      <section id="work">
        <h1>My Projects</h1>
        <div class="line"></div>
        <div class="grid">
          <div class="project">
            <a href="#">
              <img src="#" alt="">
              <p><span><</span> Lorem Ipsum <span>/></span></p>
            </a>
          </div>
          <div class="project">
            <a href="#">
              <img src="#" alt="">
              <p><span><</span> Lorem Ipsum <span>/></span></p>
            </a>
          </div>
          <div class="project">
            <a href="#">
              <img src="#" alt="">
              <p><span><</span> Lorem Ipsum <span>/></span></p>
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: El código debe ir _en la pregunta misma_. Si el enlace llega a caer, la parte más importante de la pregunta se perderá. Pulsa en [edit] para corregir tu pregunta.

Comment: Y por favor, agregalo como texto, ya que estás, mira [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida y obtengas una mejor respuesta, y de paso evitar votos negativos y/o que tu pregunta sea eliminada.

Comment: Dale perfecto,si lo que pasa es que no me dejaba subir el código, decía que era mucho

Comment: @Bhowli no se preocupe, ya lo edité por usted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Estás dando un ancho fijo a tu `container`, de la cual es incorrecto, ya que de esta forma aparecerá el scroll horizontal cuando el ancho de la pantalla sea menor al ancho fijo de tu `container`. Podrías darle un ancho del `100%` para que ocupe siempre todo el ancho de la pantalla, así ya no se mostraría el scroll de abajo:

```
.container{
   width: 100%;
   height: 100vh;
   font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif;
}
```

Y si quieres asegurarte de que el scroll desaparezca siempre, puedes hacerlo con `overflow-x: hidden;`:

```
.container{
   width: 100%;
   height: 100vh;
   font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif;
   overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Comment: perfecto,ahi funciona muchas gracias

Answer (score 1):

EL problema es el `width` de `container`, quita el `width` y agrega lo que ya tenías en `work`

```
.container{
    width: 100vw; -- ELIMINAR
    height: 100vh;
    font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif;
}

#work{
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```